# How to bind multiple css classes in a table row element?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

**I'm new to Vuejs2.0 and trying to bind multiple css classes to a table row element.**

> Here's my view (and my attempt):

```
<tr v-for="icon in icons">
    <td><i class="fa fa-" v-bind:class="icon.css"></i></td>
    <td>{{icon.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

**The `td` element with the css classes should be successfully rendered as so:**

```
<td><i class="fa fa-car"></i></td>
```

> Here's my model/data (snipped for brevity):

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        icons: [ 
            { "name": "Car", "css": "car" }, { "name": "Airplane", "css": "airplane" } 
        ]
    }
});
```

**How would I get this successfully rendered ? Thank you.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<tr v-for="icon in icons">
    <td><i class="fa" :class="'fa-' + icon.css"></i></td>
    <td>{{icon.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Or

```
<tr v-for="icon in icons">
    <td><i :class="'fa fa-' + icon.css"></i></td>
    <td>{{icon.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @redshift You're welcome. Then please mark the answer as correct and finish this one.

Comment: I just did. Also, here's a similar question now: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42348292/2420614