# How to bind CSS class into an HTML code tag?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

**I have data like so:**

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    icons: [ 
        { "name": "Car", "css": "car" }, { "name": "Airplane", "css": "airplane" } 
    ]
  }
});
```

**And I want to bind the `css` value to my view inside an HTML `<code>` element and formatted and rendered as so:**

```
<i class="fa fa-car></i>
```

**Here's my attempt using Vuejs2.0:**

```
<code>%lt;i class="fa" :class="'fa-' + icon.css">&lt;/i&gt;</code>
```

**Unfortunately, the DOM is rendered like so:**

```
<i class="fa" :class="'fa-' + icon.css"></i>
```

**How do I make this work? Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to iterate inside your icons array, you can use a template with the v-for directive :

```
<template v-for="icon in icons">
    <i class="fa fa-{{ icon.css }}></i>
</template>
```